# How to update Firebase database constantly with GPS coordinates in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase

I am currently building a running app, that will update the coordinates of the runner to the database in Firebase in real-time.

I only get it uploading when the app starts up.

Should I make a loop that constantly uploads the position?

Comment: There are a number of other questions similar to this and it's pretty open ended about what you *should* do - it depends on  your use case. Do you want to update Firebase when the position changes? When the position changes by x amount? Every 30 seconds? Every 10 minutes? Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

A good way to go about this is to set up a timer. For example, if you want to update a users location every second

create an NSTimer with a timer interval of 1 second and in the selector function update the coordinates